# Mature, fully-featured, well-supported ONVIF client libraries in Python, C, or C++?

Tags: library, python, c++

ONVIF is a standard that has been around for 10 or so years now.. but it seems like there are only a few client libraries for performing ONVIF discovery and control and they are all either low quality, feature-lacking, or not widely used / abandoned. I've been trying to find a library that can perform a simple scan of the network and tell me what ONVIF devices it found but I absolutely have been unable to do so.

What I've found so far

https://github.com/quatanium/python-onvif - this seems to only work at controlling an ONVIF device once it's been found on the network.

https://github.com/linkingvision/rapidonvif/issues/11 - has build issues reported, main README says that you need to email some dev for newer code?

Comment: Are you interested in device discovery only or a full ONVIF protocol stack?

Comment: I'm mostly looking or something to do device discovery and to enumerate the possible RTSP streams of cameras on the network.

Answer (score 1):

If a professional library is an option for you, consider using the LEADTOOLS Media Streaming SDK. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of this toolkit’s vendor).

The SDK supports both transmitting and receiving ONVIF streams, and it has a [free evaluation edition](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=mm) in case you haven't tried it already.
You can find more details in the following pages:

- [Implementing RTSP, ONVIF, and UDP Live Streams](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/multimedia/mediastreaming/implementing-rtsp-onvif-and-udp-live-streams.html)
- [LEAD ONVIF Source](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/multimedia/filters/filterscodecsandinterfaces-streamingfilters-onvifsource--rollup.html)

Comment: the OP seems to (only?) need device discovery through ONVIF protocol, can you please clarify if such feature is in LEADTOOLS and where is it documented?

Comment: There is support in LEADTOOLS for Web Services Dynamic Discovery (WS-Discovery). It's mentioned in [this help topic](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/multimedia/filters/onvif-source-url-syntax.html). The [LEAD ONVIF Source User Interface](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/multimedia/filters/lead-onvif-source-user-interface.html) contains the search button and dialog that implement the discovery.

Answer (score 1):

Came upon this : [Valkka](https://elsampsa.github.io/valkka-examples/_build/html/index.html).
I have not read it yet. Hoping that this might be a useful pointer.